can anyone help me increase solana transaction fee? or increase transaction speed
here is my codes
async sendSplTransaction(wallet, {to, value, mintAddress, decimals, fee}) {
    const recipientPubKey = new PublicKey(to);
    const mintPubKey = new PublicKey(mintAddress);
    const bigValue = this.convertToBigInt(value, decimals);
    const recentBlockhash = await this.provider.connection.getLatestBlockhash();
    let currentBlockheight = await this.provider.connection.getBlockHeight();
    const { blockhash } = await this.provider.connection.getLatestBlockhash();
    const MAX_RETRIES = 3;
    let retryCount = 0;

    while (retryCount < MAX_RETRIES) {
        try {
            const senderATA = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(mintPubKey, this.keypair.publicKey);
            const recipientATA = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(mintPubKey, recipientPubKey);

            console.log('Sender pubkey:', this.keypair.publicKey.toString());
            console.log('Sender ATA:', senderATA.toString());
            console.log('Mint address:', mintAddress);

            let senderAccountInfo =  await this.provider.connection.getAccountInfo(senderATA);

            if (!senderAccountInfo) {
                console.log('Sender ATA not found. Attempting to create...');
                const transaction = new Transaction().add(
                    createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(
                        this.keypair.publicKey,
                        senderATA,
                        this.keypair.publicKey,
                        mintPubKey
                    )
                );
                await solanaWeb3.sendAndConfirmTransaction(this.provider.connection, transaction, [this.keypair]);
                console.log('Sender ATA created successfully');
            }

            const senderBalance = await this.provider.connection.getTokenAccountBalance(senderATA);
            console.log('Sender token balance:', senderBalance.value.uiAmount);

            if (senderBalance.value.uiAmount < value) {
                throw new Error(`Insufficient balance. Current balance: ${senderBalance.value.uiAmount}`);
            }

            const transaction = new Transaction({
                recentBlockhash: recentBlockhash.blockhash,
                feePayer: this.keypair.publicKey
            });
            transaction.recentBlockhash = blockhash;
            transaction.feePayer = this.keypair.publicKey;
            transaction.fee = fee;

            const recipientAccountInfo = await this.provider.connection.getAccountInfo(recipientATA);

            if (!recipientAccountInfo) {
                transaction.add(
                    createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(
                        this.keypair.publicKey,
                        recipientATA,
                        recipientPubKey,
                        mintPubKey
                    )
                );
            }

            transaction.add(
                createTransferInstruction(
                    senderATA,
                    recipientATA,
                    this.keypair.publicKey,
                    bigValue,
                    [],
                    TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
                )
            );

            transaction.lastValidBlockHeight = currentBlockheight + 150;

            const txid = await solanaWeb3.sendAndConfirmTransaction(
                this.provider.connection,
                transaction,
                [this.keypair],
                {
                    commitment: "confirmed",
                    skipPreflight: true
                }
            );

            console.log('Transaction successful. Txid:', txid);
            return { success: true, data: { txid } };
        } catch (error) {
            if (error.message.includes('block height')) {
                retryCount++;
                const MAX_RETRY_DELAY = 30000;
                const delay = Math.min(2 ** retryCount * 1000, MAX_RETRY_DELAY);
                console.log(`Transaction failed, retrying in ${delay / 1000} seconds...`);
                await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, delay));
            } else {
                return { success: false, data: null, error: error.message };
            }
        }
    }

    return { success: false, data: null, error: 'Transaction retries exhausted.' };
}


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Some areas you could try troubleshooting with are,

Experiment with different RPC providers. Chainstack and triton.one are good ones to start with.

Try adding a priority fee instruction.


The code below

async function recentPriorityFees() {
    const url =
        "https://nd-326-444-187.p2pify.com/9de47db917d4f69168e3fed02217d15b/";
    const options = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            accept: "application/json",
            "content-type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            id: 1,
            jsonrpc: "2.0",
            method: "getRecentPrioritizationFees",
            params: [["TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA"]],
        }),
    };
    let resp = (await (await fetch(url, options)).json()) as any;
    return resp.result[0].prioritizationFee;
}


// ----- snip 

const recentFee = await recentPriorityFees();
const PRIORITY_FEE_INSTRUCTIONS = ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitPrice({
    microLamports: recentFee,
});

transaction.add(
                createTransferInstruction(
                    senderATA,
                    recipientATA,
                    this.keypair.publicKey,
                    bigValue,
                    [],
                    TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
                )
            ).add(PRIORITY_FEE_INSTRUCTIONS);

// ---- snip

If you prefer UMI, here's how to use it's inbuild RPC plugin to make the call to fetch the fees for Ore
async function fetchRecentPriorityFees() {
    return (await umi.rpc.call("getRecentPrioritizationFees", [
        ["oreV2ZymfyeXgNgBdqMkumTqqAprVqgBWQfoYkrtKWQ"],
    ])) as any;
}

fetchRecentPriorityFees()
    .then((res) => console.log(res[0].prioritizationFee))
    .catch(console.error);

